# How to divide int * type?

Tags: c, pointers, math, operators, divide

I'm trying to find from input to if is "Armstrong Number" or not.  Here's my code. Probably I have another arrow but I can't divide (/) or multiplication (*) with int * variables. Why is that?
Also what is the best way to finding "Armstrong Number" and put information for user?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
   int n = 0, c = 0, result = 0;
   printf( "Enter a number: " );
   scanf("%d", &n);
   int digit = log10(n)+1;

   int ntemp1 = n;
   while (ntemp1 != 0){
      ntemp1 /= 10;
      c++;
   }

   ntemp1 = n;
   for (int i = 0; i < c; i++){
      result += pow(ntemp1 % 10, c);
      ntemp1 /= 10;
   }
   if (result == n)
      printf("\nIt is an Armstrong Number!\n");
   else
      printf("\nIt is not an Armstrong Number!\n");
}
```

Also can I make this with arrays or maybe have different ways?

Comment: There are so many issues with this code that I stopped reading it. Is your compiler not giving you any warnings?

Comment: Do you know what `int*` means / have you learned what pointers are? Note that the line `scanf("%d", s);` has undefined behavior since it's trying to write to a null pointer.

Comment: If i need to find the entering number is armstrong number or not i need to check one by one i was think.

Comment: It's giving errors yes but i still learning C and English togather.

Comment: @SCK So delete most of your code, and start reintroducing it a line at a time, solving errors and warnings as they come up. And read about pointers, you're completely misusing them. There is too much wrong here to comment on. Start by trying to read a number from stdin. The only actionable question here is *"i can't divide (/) or multiplication (\*) with int \* variables. Why is that?*" - Because they're pointers, and division and multiplication (usually) make no sense.

Comment: Fix the errors then. If you don't understand them, [edit] your question to tell us which errors you need help with.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your edit of the question made it completely useless as the mentioned error was not present any more. If you found the solution of your problem, write an answer (if there isn't any available yet). I've rolled back your edit.

Answer (score 1):

> ```c
> scanf("%d", s);
> ```

Undefined behaviour since `s` is NULL. You need to pass a pointer to somewhere `scanf` can store an `int`.

---

> ```c
> scopy /= 10;
> ```

Dividing a pointer makes no sense. Division requires a number.

---

> ```c
> scopy[j]
> ```

If we ignore the division to get to this spot, you assigned NULL to `scopy`, and  is derefencing a NULL pointer is undefined behaviour.

---

As for fixes, I don't know what you are trying to do, but your code should start with

```c
unsigned n = 0;
printf( "Enter a number: " );
if ( scanf( "%u", &n ) != 1 ) {
   fprintf( stderr, "Invalid input.\n" );
   exit( 1 );
}
```